# 2D array in C with pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand below code output:

```
int counter = 0; 
int aMatrix[5][5]; 
register int *aPtr; 
int i, j; 
for (i=0; i<5; i++) 
for (j=0; j<5; j++) 
aMatrix[i][j] = counter++; 
aPtr = &aMatrix[1][1]; printf("%d\n", aPtr[2]);
```

Referring to the sample code above, what will be the value of "aPtr[2]", after execution?

please help me to understand why I am getting 8 as output.

Comment: This might help. http://fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) 
for (j=0; j<5; j++) 
aMatrix[i][j] = counter++;
```

After the execution of for loop your `aMatrix` contains-

```
aMatrix[0] --> 0  1  2  3  4 
aMatrix[1] --> 5  6  7  8  9
aMatrix[2] --> 10 11 12 13 14
aMatrix[3] --> 15 16 17 18 19
aMatrix[4] --> 20 21 22 23 24
```

So `aMatrix[1][1]` contains `6`, you are assigning the address of `aMatrix[1][1]` to `aPtr`.
That is `aPtr[0] = 6`, `aPtr[1] = 7` and `aPtr[2] = 8`. So Obviously you will get output `8`.

Answer (score 5):

After the assignment, the matrix becomes:

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
...
```

With

```
aPtr = &aMatrix[1][1];
```

`aPtr[0]` is the same as `aMatrix[1][1]`, so `aPtr[2]` is the same as `aMatrix[1][3]`, which is `8` in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

i'd like to add that the multidimensional arrays are stored contiguously in memory. statement

```
int aMatrix[5][5];
```

is evaluated by compiler to

```
int (*aMatrix)[5];
```

so it is a pointer to 5 element array of ints. that's the size of your column. C doesn't check for boundaries and compiler doesn't know that there are 5 rows in your matrix.
furthermore, statement

```
aPtr = &aMatrix[1][1];
```

is evaluated to

```
aPtr = &(*(*(aMatrix + 1) + 1));
```

so it takes the address of aMatrix, by adding 1 it really adds 5, because aMatrix points to 5 ints. then, it is dereferenced and now just 1 is added. then, another dereference and aPtr points to address of that cell. 
aPtr points to one int. so aPtr[2] adds 2. to sum up, 5+1+2 = 8.

what aMatrix really look like is

```
aMatrix ---> [0 1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8 9] [10 11 12 13 14] [15 16 17 18 19] [20 21 22 23 24]
              ^                      |______________|
           aMatrix[0][0]                aMatrix[2]
```

you could get the same output by, for instance, writing following code:

```
int* testPtr = &aMatrix[0][0];
printf("%d\n",testPtr[8]);
```